# A relation between component and quasi-component

Tags: general-topology

As E.R asked at  [Component and quasi-component](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309171/component-and-quasi-component,I)  think the following question has a positive answer. Am I right?

Question: Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two connected components of a completely regular space $X$ such that there exists $x\in X$ with $C_1\cup C_2\subseteq C_x$ and let $f$ be a real-valued, continuous function  on $X$ such that $f (C_1\cup C_2)\subseteq\{0, 1   \}$ and $f(C_1)=\{0\}$. How can we show that  $f(C_2)=\{0\}$?

Comment: Let $X$ be any metric space with a disconnected quasi-component $C_x$.  Then let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two different components in $C_x$.  These components are closed in $X$, so there is a mapping $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f[C_0]=0$ and $f[C_1]=1$.  So it is not necessarily the case that  $f[C_1]$ is $0$ when $f[C_0]=0$.

Comment: I removed the [gt.geometric-topology] and [at.algebraic-topology] tags, as this question is neither.